# Why do I need to confirm my cancellation of a question edit?

Tags: support, edits, cancel, confirmation

I just edited a question and then rejected my edits by clicking "Cancel". Then a pop-up comes up that asks for confirmation of my cancellation.

Is that really needed?

[image]

Comment: Probably a matter of personal preferences, but I don't mind it.  Once in a blue moon is keeps me from accidentally jumping to a new question and losing my work.

Comment: *"OMG, I accidentally clicked on the cancel link instead of the button and now all my work is gone. Why on earth don't you guys ask for confirmation first?"*

Comment: @Bart ok i see the point. This is clearly a feature (and not a bug). Maybe i need to adjust my mouse.

Comment: I agree with @Bart - when cancel and save are so close, miss-clicks happens. Only if cancel would be far away from any other clickable element confirmation might be vomited, but even then what does it hurt to have it? If you click edit, it means you have some edit in mind and cancel is not really an expected action.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes the prompt would be needed. It won't allow you to cancel the work immediately if you accidentally clicked on the cancel button.

This [comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/224542/why-do-i-need-to-confirm-my-cancellation-of-a-question-edit/224543#comment732924_224542) explains you clearly.